# Populate a dictionary recursively?

Tags: f#, recursion, dictionary, types, type-inference

I'm testing the following code to populate a dictionary recursively. However the type inference  does not seem to recognize the dictionary type.  I've tried using a type annotation but that did not seem to help.

Are there some restrictions on the use of dictionaries in a recursive routine. Do I need to make the dictionary mutable since I expect to change it during iterations.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

////dictionary recursion test

let pop_dict tlist = 
   // let rec inner tlist acc ddict:Dictionary<string,int> =
    let rec inner tlist acc ddict =
       match tlist with 
            | [] ->  ddict.Add ("dummykey", acc)                             
            | x::xs  -> inner xs  (x::acc) ddict
    let  ddict = Dictionary<string,int>()
    inner tlist [] ddict 


// Main Entry Point
let main() =

    let tlist = [1;2;3;4]
    let d = pop_dict tlist

main()
```

Comment: You want a mutable dictionary with one key ("dummykey") that contains the list you passed in? let dic = Dictionary<string,int list>(); dic.add("dummykey", [1,2,3,4])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your types don't match up.

You're trying to add an `int list` (which is what `acc` is) to a dictionary that is supposed to contain `int`s.

Apart from that, however, the reason that the compiler cannot infer the type of `ddict` is. Remember, when the type checker determines types for the function, it doesn't look at what it gets called with later. It only has the following information available:

```
let rec inner tlist acc ddict =
   match tlist with 
        | [] -> ddict.Add ("dummykey", acc)                             
        | x::xs  -> inner xs  (x::acc) ddict
```

That means, that the only information it knows about `ddict` when it compiles the function, is that it has a method named `Add`, which `string * 'a list -> ?`.

To fix it, change

```
let rec inner tlist acc ddict =
```

to

```
let rec inner tlist acc (ddict:Dictionary<string,int>) =
```

You still have the trouble with the mismatching types on the dictionary, however, so you probably want it to be `Dictionary<string, int list>`, if you plan on storing `int list`s in it.

Comment: Good explanation - getting/checking the type checking rules clear is maybe the the trickiest part of learning F# - however it does focus the mind and (hopefully) improves our coding skills.

Answer (score 1):

is that what you wanted?

```
let pop_dict tlist = 
    let rec inner tlist acc (ddict:Dictionary<string,int list>) =
       match tlist with 
            | [] ->  ddict.Add ("dummykey", acc)                             
            | x::xs  -> inner xs  (x::acc) ddict
    let  ddict = Dictionary<string,int list>()
    inner tlist [] ddict 


// Main Entry Point
let main() =

    let tlist = [1;2;3;4]
    let d = pop_dict tlist
    ()
```